# GKLocalPlayer.authenticated always returns false

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Game Center in my app and I'm having some problem with the GKLocalPlayer.authenticated attribute. Regardless if the authentication process is successful or not, localPlayer.authenticated always returns false. This also happens if my device is already logged in to Game Center.
I get this both on actual device (iPhone 6s) and simulator (tried several).

The only information I've found about this suggests that there is a problem with the time settings but they seem to be fine.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
private static let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer()

static func authenticateLocalPlayer() {
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = { (viewController, error) -> Void in
        if let viewController = viewController {
            if let rootViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
                rootViewController.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        } else if localPlayer.authenticated {
            gameCenterEnabled = true
            let defaultCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
            defaultCenter.postNotificationName("local_player_authenticated", object: nil)
        } else {
            gameCenterEnabled = false
        }

        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

static func isAuthenticated() -> Bool {
    return localPlayer.authenticated
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled Game Center service from xcode?

Comment: Yup, I can get my app to log the user in to Game Center and everything, but the localPlayer.authenticated is always false, regardless if the user logs in through my app or if they were already logged in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad, looks like I made a little mistake when translating this code from Objective-C. It's supposed to be

```
GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
```

not

```
GKLocalPlayer()
```